# How To Use The First Layers Of Model In PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have uploaded a certain model

```
from efficientnet_pytorch import EfficientNet
model = EfficientNet.from_pretrained(model)
```

And I can see the model:

```
print(model.state_dict())
```

The model contains quite a few layers, and I want to take only the first 50. Please tell me how I can do this.

Comment: Do you want to **print** only the first 50 layers, is that it?

Comment: No, I want a model with the first 50 layers from this model

Comment: As it is currently implemented, you'd have to change the source code, because it is not a `Sequential` module. Nonetheless, maybe [`extract_endpoints()`](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/5fbffa4461e0f0e944da6b1dc1c2e1441b108d0d/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py#L231-L273) or [`extract_features()`](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/5fbffa4461e0f0e944da6b1dc1c2e1441b108d0d/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py#L275-L298) could help you.

Comment: May be I can load model from state_dict?
state_dict = collections.OrderedDict(list(self.model.state_dict().items())[:50] )

Comment: This won't give you a model, but only the weights.

Comment: It's strange. I can get the result of the model, but I can't get the result of the intermediate layers?

Comment: extract_endpoints() or extract_features() helped a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think this should do the trick:

```py
model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.classifier.children())[:50])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this model does not work, probably because the computation graph is not saved
NotImplementedError